# Sorting multidimensional array and displaying it

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, asp-classic

Here's part of my code.

```
<%
Dim lineData,fso,filea,fileb,filec
s=request.querystring("query")

set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

a(0,0)=0
a(1,0)=" - Entries in File A"
set filea = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("FileA.txt"), 1, true)
do until lone.AtEndOfStream
    lineData = lcase(filea.ReadLine())
    if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
    a(0,0)=a(0,0)+1
    end if
Loop

a(0,1)=0
a(1,1)=" - Entries in File B"
set fileb = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("FileB.txt"), 1, true)
do until mile.AtEndOfStream
    lineData = lcase(fileb.ReadLine())
    if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
    a(0,1)=a(0,1)+1
    end if
Loop


a(0,2)=0
a(1,2)=" - Entries in File C"
set filec = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("FileC.txt"), 1, true)
do until payne.AtEndOfStream
    lineData = lcase(filec.ReadLine())
    if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
    a(0,2)=a(0,2)+1
    end if
Loop
%>
```

The code essentially looks for the number of entries in a text file. What I need is it to be sorted such that the file with the most number of entries comes first.

Suppose there are 10 entries in FileA, 12 in FileB and 7 in FileC. I'd like the output to be displayed like this:

```
12 - Entries in File B
10 - Entries in File A
7 - Entries in File C
```

I'm guessing it won't be too complicated since response.write(a(0,i)&a(1,i)) will work. I just need help with the loop or any sorting method if there is one.
Any help I can get in here will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a "neo-answer" that should help you get to where you want to go, both in the short- and long-term.

1) First, a suggestion for further reading to help you address this sort of problem in a more general way -- and to help you develop your "chops" as you go. You can Google the term "bubble sort" and get a whole host of interesting and mostly helpful input, but here's a link you probably will find most directly helpful, from a brief series of articles on sorting from the 4 Guys from Rolla site, which back in the day was THE place for quality writing on ASP:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153403/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/011601-1.shtml

You will see that there is a link to an introductory article at the top of this one that covers one-dimensional array sorting, and I recommend it as well. For one, it introduces another sort method, QuickSort, and having multiple tools in your toolbox is almost never a bad idea. (As you will discover, bubble sorting is often the easiest to envision and implement, but because its performance is essentially linear based on the number of items being sorted, can become a performance problem on larger datasets.) Go ahead, check it out; I'll wait 'til you get back...

2) OK, to give you a more concrete approach to address your specific situation here, if the number of files you're reviewing isn't going to be too large, you can do a sort of "final pass" sort to present your results in the desired order.

First, you'll want to introduce a simple global counting variable up toward the top of your code:

```
dim intMaxEntries
intMaxEntries = 0
```

Then, at the end of each of your file-parsing runs, you'll want to check the number of entries against intMaxEntries and update intMaxEntries if the number of entries just read in is greater.

```
if a(0, 1) > intMaxEntries then
    intMaxEntries = a(0, 1)
end if
```

You'll do right after each file reading loop, so the comparison in the above snippet would be done for a(0, 1), a(1, 1), and a(2, 1). More on that repetitive logic at the end.

After you've done all the file reads, intMaxEntries will have the maximum number of entries you've found in one of the files. Then, you can just step down from that value and print out entry counts in the correct order when they match your countdown:

```
dim i, j
for i = intMaxEntries to 0 step -1
    for j = 0 to ubound(a)         'By default gives the upper bound of the 1st dimen.
        if a(j, 1) = i then
            Response.Write i & a(j, 2) & "<BR>"
        end if
    next j
next i
```

This is more than a bit of a hack, and I would encourage you to opt instead for doing a proper sort of your array so that you have something more generalizably useful, but it will work to get you where you want to go, especially if the number of files -- or the maximum number of entries -- isn't too large. You could also clean up my example by introducing the possibility of breaking out of the loops when all the files are accounted for, but I'll let you figure out if that's necessary.

3) You may have just simplified the codebase to get the concept across more cleanly (for which I applaud you if true), but just in case, I would encourage you to look at ways to modularize your work by building your file reading functionality as a function that is simply called with the file and string comparison information needed. (Also, probably an artifact of your snipping, but the "lone", "mile" and "Payne" references in there don't make sense; assuming those are the FSOs you are instantiating and have just forgotten to change them to fileA, fileB and fileC.)

Hope that helps a bit,

Bret

Comment: That helps a lot actually.
Regarding the last part, how do I "modularize your work by building your file reading functionality as a function that is simply called with the file and string comparison information needed"?
And yes, I forgot to change those names into fileA, fileB and fileC.
The program is meant to look into movie subtitles for a search term.  (lone, mile and payne were variables I assigned for  "The Lone Ranger", "8 Mile" and "Max Payne".
On a side note, I'm fairly new to ASP and was wondering how I could publish this site. Or is it only possible with ASP.NET?

Comment: Last question first: you can certainly publish this site. IIS (Microsoft's web server) will handle ASP for you quite easily -- I can run it on my local machine (Windows). Here's a tutorial you can use as a starting point: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/scenario-build-a-classic-asp-website-on-iis

Comment: On your first question, that's a longer answer that will require some work on your part, but let me answer it with a question:

Do you have 24 chunks of code that basically read in each of the subtitle files you're working with? Wouldn't it make sense to define a single function and simply call it 24 times? (And wouldn't it then make even more sense to do a little extra work to simply have your app scour the target directory and parse each subtitle file it finds there without having to set a hardwired number?)

Comment: Your code would then go from 24 copies the same task that will need to be modified whenever conditions change, to something that would work with whatever you threw at it, something a bit like this:

s=request.querystring("query") 
Call CountSubtitleHits(s, ServerMapPath("Your directory here")

and you would then do the *real* work of iterating through your directory and counting up the hits of the phrase you're looking for and printing them out in that subroutine (CountSubtitleHits).

Here's a link to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@bret
Someone else came through.
Here's a code that worked perfectly.
Would this be an example of "bubble sort"?

```
for k=23 to 0 Step-1
    for j=0 to k
        if (a(0,j)<a(0,j+1)) then
            t1=a(0,j+1)
            t2=a(1,j+1)
            a(0,j+1)=a(0,j)
            a(1,j+1)=a(1,j)
            a(0,j)=t1
            a(1,j)=t2
        end If
    next
next
for i=0 to 24
    if a(0,i)>0 then
        response.write (a(0,i)&a(1,i)&"<br>")
    end if
next
```

Comment: It is, and in a way is an example of the question I raised about specific vs. generalized/modular code, specifically: why do you have 23/24 hardwired into the above algorithm? I understand what they represent, but the point is, wouldn't it be better to make your codebase more flexible? What if you decide you want to add more movies to your search? If you do it right, you would simply add the file(s) to the relevant directory and your code would handle the new file(s) without modification.

Comment: So instead of 

for k = 23 to 0 step -1

you could have:

for k = (ubound(a) - 1) to 0 step -1

and so forth. The idea is to make your application as efficient as possible without making it brittle. Adding files, or changing what you search for, or similar sorts of changes should be able to be done with either no or minimal rework on your part.

Comment: P.S. Glad you got your immediate need solved, and hope I've helped in figuring out how to make it a bit more robust. 

Cheers,

Bret

Comment: Finally got some time to work on the code again. I took your advice and have ended up with a much shorter code. It now looks into all text files in a directory and it's great now. Adding more movies is a LOT easier thanks to you.
However, I have some trouble sorting it now. Since I cant write the code as a comment, I've added another answer. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out once again.

Comment: Hah. Got it working with no issues whatsoever now. Thanks a lot @Bret. :')

Comment: Hey. Thanks again. But now I've got another issue.
I really need your help once again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608117/how-do-i-get-a-variable-to-work-within-double-quotes-in-asp-classic

Answer (score 0):

```
set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(server.mappath("Files"))
set objfiles = objFolder.Files

Function filesearch(name)

set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(server.mappath(filename),1, true)
do until searchname.AtEndOfStream
lineData = lcase(searchname.ReadLine())
if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
instances = instances + 1
end if
Loop

End Function

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
filesearch(objFile)
Response.Write filename & "<br>" & instances & "<br>" & "<br>"
Next

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

There are a few rough edges but what really bothers me now is the sorting. Where do I keep the bubble sort code?

EDIT:
I've got it work perfect with the following code.

```
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
filesearch(objFile)
i = i + 1
a(0,i) = instances
a(1,i) = filename
Next
```

I was also wondering if there's anyway I could also write the total number of instances. I was able to do it before with:

```
for i=0 to 43
    entries=entries+a(0,i)
next
```

I cant seem to make it work now.

EDIT:
Works now with:

```
for i = 0 to n
entries = entries + a(0,i)
next
```