# How do I get a variable to work within double quotes in ASP-classic?

Tags: variables, asp-classic

The following code is part of a function that is being called for each file the program finds during it's search through a directory.

```
set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(server.mappath(filename),1, true)
do until searchname.AtEndOfStream
lineData = lcase(searchname.ReadLine())
if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
instances = instances + 1
end if
Loop
```

This the part of my code I'm confused with. This code worked perfectly yesterday. I made a few edits but mostly with HTML and CSS. When I pulled this code out today to optimize it better, I just keep getting a permission denied error with this line.

```
set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(server.mappath(filename),1, true)
```

The problem is that the folder the code scans through contains some files that have more than one word. So it's essential that I get the "filename" variable within double quotes. I've been looking everywhere for a solution and none of them have been helpful yet. Is this even possible or is there a workaround?

Any help would be much appreciated here.

EDIT: As requested here's the code that gets the filename. Although no idea how it pertains to my question.

```
Function filesearch(name)

ext = instr(name,".txt")
vdirectoryvalue = instr(name,"Files\")+6
idname = mid(name,vdirectoryvalue,ext)
vdirectory = len(idname) - 4
filename = left(idname,vdirectory)
instances = 0

set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(server.mappath(idname), 1, true)
do until searchname.AtEndOfStream
lineData = lcase(searchname.ReadLine())
if instr(lineData,s)>0 then
instances = instances + 1
end if
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: why is the last Parameter in openTextfile true? when it's true, the file will be created if it does not exist... furthermore could you show more code? are you Looping through a directory?

Comment: @ulluoink Yes. I've also updated the original post to include more of the code. Would a "false" value as the last parameter help?

Comment: Have you double checked your permissions, to make sure they have not been reset etc? Not sure why people are asking for your loop code the issue occurs before any of that, so pointless posting it. Have you tried outputting just `server.mappath(filename)` to see what `MapPath()` returns?

Comment: I'm not sure about permissions. How do I go about it?
Yeah, been wondering why he wanted to see the rest of the code.

But is there no way I can have the file name include multiple words and still use it in Server.MapPath(filename)?

Comment: the reason i wanted to see more code is that it is not clear where the variable filename comes from. still i do not see where that variable is defined and filled. why not post the whole function filesearch?

Comment: That is unnecessary isn't it?
Just help me out with the problem I'm having. Please.

Comment: well if that's your opinion... then i only can say that the posted code works for me...

Comment: I've added the complete code to the original post. The reason I didn't post the part of the code is because it was messy. When I requested the file name it came along with the full directory. Anyway, I've updated the original post. Hope it helps.

Comment: you make a server.mappath on idname. idname only consists the filename (without any path). so Server.mappath will give you the path of your web root. but as far as i can see the files you are trying to search are in a Sub Directory named "files"? now your script trys to create the file in the web root (because of the Parameter in opentextfile). but there you do not have the correct permissions...

Comment: After having read your comment, I realized that instead of having to somehow write the variable in double quotes, I could just write the code as set searchname = objFSO.OpenTextFile(("C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Subtitle\Files\"&idname), 1, true)

It works now!

Comment: If I'm following, what about using the Chr function? Chr(34) will return a double quote. Something like `filename = Chr(34) & left(idname,vdirectory) & Chr(34)` would encase filename in double quotes.